# Munkres Topology Exercise 2.q

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have another doubt regarding a question from Munkres' Topology (another one on cartesian products, sorry!).

I have to determine if the following statement is true:

$$(A\times B)-(C\times D)=(A-C)\times (B-D)$$

What I did was:

If the ordered pair $(a,b)\in LHS$, then we must have that $$(a,b)\in (A\times B)\implies a\in A, b\in B$$
$$(a,b)\not\in (C\times D)\implies a\not\in C, b\not\in D$$

Now, this means that:
$$a\in(A-C)$$
$$b\in(B-D)$$

So that $(a,b)\in RHS$. Therefore $LHS\subseteq RHS$. Now, going the other way...

If $(a,b)\in RHS$, then:
$$a\in (A-C)\implies a\in A, a\not\in C$$
$$b\in (B-D)\implies b\in B, b\not\in D$$

Which means that:
$$(a,b)\in (A\times B)$$
$$(a,b)\not\in (C\times D)$$

So $(a,b)\in LHS$, and $LHS\supseteq RHS\implies LHS=RHS$.

According to the website that I'm checking my answers against, though, the correct solution should give $LHS\supset RHS$. This implies I did something wrong in the first part, where I show that $LHS\subseteq RHS$. What did I do wrong there? I'm really having trouble getting this, I think.

Thanks, and sorry for the inconvenience. Usually I'm able to grasp math more easily :(

Comment: $(a,b)\not\in C\times D \implies a\not\in A\mbox{ or }b\not\in D$.

Comment: @Zircht Do you mean $a \notin C$?

Comment: @Code-Guru Yes. Thanks.

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you. One final doubt: is it true that $(a,b)\in (A\times B)\implies a\in A$, $\textit{and}$ $b\in B$?

Comment: Yeah, that is true. You're welcome. :)